# Git diff, no new line, what is changed?

Tags: git

I did git diff shows:

```
-}
\ No newline at end of file
+}
```

What is changed? It seems no difference to me..

BTW: I offen see red 0 and return in Github commit, What is that mean?

Comment: Are you making the changes on windows/linux ? You might have changed the EOL character from '\n', default in linux, to '\r\n', default in windows, if you are working on multiple platforms.

Comment: @snyder No, an added `\r` is highlighted with `^M` in the git diff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original version of the file had no newline character at the end of the last line.
You've probably edited the file with a decent editor in the meantime, so now it does have one.

It's definitely not a trailing space. That would be highlighted with red.

Comment: This is the actual answer. "No newline at end of file" means what it says. The other answers/comments are lame guesses that imply the message "No newline at end of file" means something completely different from what it **says**. The only thing slightly hard to understand about that message should be which file it's talking about: it applies to the file in the preceding line. (If the second file had no trailing newline, then `\ No newline at end of file` would be after the `+}` line.)

Answer (score -1):

You might have added **"space"** near the brace }. This is one of the reasons. Check that.

Comment: a `space` is not a `newline` character

Comment: Yeah.. What I meant is "}" is different from "} " at the end of file. Also, I mentioned this would be one of the reasons which causes the change in the file. Obviously, what SzG answered is the correct one. But, even if we add "space" near the brace will show the same kinda status when we do "git status".. Thanks.. :) :)

Comment: that's a totally different issue then - you might add a space - or for that matter any character - somewhere in a file and get a message from Git that the file has changed. this is however definitely not "one of the reasons" for above message which is very clear about a `newline at end of file`